# How can lock a folder

Tags: node.js

I am working in a project that have file processing. Files are coming from another application and is large in number. Now I want to lock that folder for other application till scan it's files and process. After processing all files will removed and unlock this folder. I have googled it, but solution not found. Is there any method using node.js? Please suggest.

Comment: What do you mean by "lock"? There can be no other writers? No other readers? Both?

Comment: No other writer. Reader are only my application.

Answer (score 0):

For my file system synchronization, I tend to use the [lockfile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lockfile) module. It allows a function to lock a file/folder, preventing access until it is freed (Effectively a mutex). An example of what you are trying to do can be found on their npm page:

```
var lockFile = require('lockfile');
lockFile.lock('some-file.lock', opts, function (er) {
  // if the er happens, then it failed to acquire a lock. 
  // if there was not an error, then the file was created, 
  // and won't be deleted until we unlock it. 

  // do my stuff, free of interruptions 
  // then, some time later, do: 
  lockFile.unlock('some-file.lock', function (er) {
    // er means that an error happened, and is probably bad. 
  })
});
```

Where "some-file.lock" is the file/directory you are trying to lock.

Comment: What functions does it use internally?

Comment: @Pacerier wow this is an old answer. The lockfile module afaik just uses standard stat/write file syscalls - it's just using the files existence as a mutex.